# Akka - understand the actors model

Tags: akka, microservices

I have been learning Akka for few days and I have a simple questions to understand it well. How should be the application architecture created for REST service which using actors? Actors should be:

- A simple component (for example Service layer, DAO, controllers, etc)?
- An Actor should be a buisness logic element. For example I have a business logic which should be spearate into tasks which are actors?
- An Actor = microservice. It is a high level layer. Every microservice in application should work as an separate actor?

I cannot understand it in this way - how should I use actors in correct way? If I create a REST service with layers (controllers, services, DAO and database), how should I separate it as actors in Akka application?

Answer (score 1):

There was a blog (likely [this](https://eng.localytics.com/akka-streams-akka-without-the-actors/)) that reflects my take on Akka Actors pretty well. I don't really use them.

Depends on who you talk with, some people are really into it whereas others may see it as an underlying essential which maybe isn't that useful on an application level.

I use actors for handling state. That's all. Otherwise it's Futures or Akka Streams. I hope you like the blog. If you still have questions after it, please shoot. I have 5+ years of Akka behind me. Happy to help.

Comment: Thanks. I will read this. So what is a difference between Akka Streams and rest api communication between services? Only that they are async?

Comment: The question is strange - they are different abstractions. REST API as such does not offer streaming.

Comment: I understand. I would like to know what is the best way to create microservices architecture. How to separate different components into actors or by using streams or futures?

Comment: Have you looked at e.g. Pluralsight for courses on that? StackOverflow is best for answering specific questions, and yours... might be too wide. It depends. Also, microservices mean different things to different people (stateful / stateless) etc.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't recommend building a REST service using raw Akka actors.  Actors are better used for encapsulating state and behavior.  For example, the loosely-coupled lightweight actors can be used for [simulating individual IoT devices](https://blog.genuine.com/2017/07/scala-iot-systems-with-akka-actors-ii/) (e.g. thermostats), each of which maintains its own internal state (e.g. cool setting) and adjusts/reports its settings via non-blocking message passing.

For REST API/service, you might want to consider using [Play](https://www.playframework.com/) which is built on top of Akka, supporting non-blocking I/O, JSON as first-class citizen, Websockets, etc.  Here's a basic example of creating a [REST service using Play](https://developer.lightbend.com/guides/play-rest-api/).

On microservice, as noted in the above link:

> Building a REST API in Play does not automatically make it a
>   "microservice" because it does not cover larger scale concerns about
>   microservices such as ensuring resiliency, consistency, or monitoring.

To incorporate microservice into your REST API, consider the [Lagom framework](https://www.lagomframework.com/) which is built on top of Play/Akka along with the [reactive](https://www.reactivemanifesto.org/) qualities.

Comment: What about Akka Http, streams and futures? Is it a way to create a rest API (Akka Http) and connect every layers in application by streams or futures. Additionally it could be possible to connect small microservices by streams? Am I right or almost? If I would like to create a system which is build of microservices what is the best way to do it? I know about Play, but I would like to use only clear Akka. Play is still a web framework.

Comment: `Play 2.6` is built on top of Akka Http which, in turn, builds on Akka Stream.  If you prefer not to use a framework, you can certainly build your own REST microservices by directly using the Akka Http and Akka Stream APIs.  This [blog post](https://danielgrigg.com/post/2017-06-04-macvendor-an-akka-stream-microservice/) seems to be on a relevant topic hence might be of interest.